# Convert screen into Primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

[image][image: data Table]

I need to convert above screen into dynamic datatable.In my screen shot domestic os will be static fields.but when i click on + button besides domestic os label, the two corresponding rows  DTJP and DCJP should come from database, initially it will be displayed as blnak row.But clicking on + button the row with input text field should be displayed on screen.i have tried  the following code:

```
                              <p:columnGroup type="header">
                                     <p:row>
                                            <p:column rowspan="2" colspan="1" headerText="Resource Type" />
                                            <p:column colspan="12" headerText="2013" />
                                            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="'14" />
                                            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="'15" />
                                            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="'16" />
                                            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="'17" />
                                     </p:row>
                                     <p:row>
                                            <p:column headerText="4" />
                                            <p:column headerText="5" />
                                            <p:column headerText="6" />
                                            <p:column headerText="7" />
                                            <p:column headerText="8" />
                                            <p:column headerText="9" />
                                            <p:column headerText="10" />
                                            <p:column headerText="11" />
                                            <p:column headerText="12" />
                                            <p:column headerText="1" />
                                            <p:column headerText="2" />
                                            <p:column headerText="3" />
                                     </p:row>

                              </p:columnGroup>

                              <p:column>
                               Employee
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>
                               <h:inputText /> 
                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>

                              </p:column>
                              <p:column>

                              </p:column>


                       </p:dataTable>
```

Edited-
I need to create a datatable in jsf using primefaces where i need to have one row in which one column contains static data with one button.When i will click on this button then the other columns(within the same row) should display some input text fields with label and data should be populated from database.It means if there are two records coming, then the column in that row should get spanned into the number of rows according to number of records.It means one column will be static and other column in that row should get dynamically spanned and some components should be added in the column within the row.please help me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Need more info. where is the data stored?